# What is the interpretation of Slater-Koster-notation?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

In the 1954-citation classic from [Slater and Koster](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.94.1498), the authors wrote (in their own notation) that using [Löwdin functions](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1950JChPh..18..365L) $\psi_n$, Bloch sums can be constructed like so:
$$
N^{1/2} \sum (\vec{R}_i) \exp i(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{R}_i) \psi_n(\vec{r} - \vec{R}_i).
$$
The authors then go on to saying that the Hamiltonian matrix elements are
$$
N^{-1} \sum (\vec{R}_i,\vec{R_j}) \exp i \vec{k} \cdot (\vec{R}_j - \vec{R}_i) \int \psi_n^*(\vec{r}-\vec{R}_i) H \psi_m(\vec{r}-\vec{R}_j) d v.
$$
Questions:

1. Can you kindly say what the symbols $(\vec{R}_i)$ and $(\vec{R}_i,\vec{R_j})$ are denoted by in notation that is common today, and the equations that define them? To avoid confusion over what *notation is common today*, perhaps we can say the notation of the [Bloch theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch%27s_theorem) article in Wikipedia is such notation.
2. Is the notation $dv$ the same as $d \vec{r}$? If it is not, please could you say what it means.

Comment: If I had to guess, I would see this as $\sum(\vec{R}_i) = \sum_i$ and $\sum(\vec{R}_i,\vec{R}_j) = \sum_{i,j}$. The sums are over all lattice vectors, I imagine, and so they're notating that explicitly. But I don't have access to the paper, and I'm not familiar with that notation, so it's just a guess.

Comment: $dv$ is the volume element, which for a three dimensional lattice would mean $d^3 \vec{r}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is commonly used for the [Tight-binding approximation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tight_binding) which is indeed derived from the Bloch theorem. More detailed information can be found in the page. Basically, the wave function is an expansion in a basis set of atomic orbitals centered at $\vec{R_i}$, when the theorem is applied this notation appears clearly with the hopping integrals between from a site $i$ to a site $j$. This article is the main reference for the expression of hopping integrals with hopping parameters. The summation is utterly a sum over neighbors, if centered on one atom $\sum (R_i)$, or $\sum (R_i,R_j)$ not centered on one atom. As it uses localized atomic orbitals, the expansion is limited to first, second or third neighbors only. This notation for this approximation is then trivial, makes sense and is commonly used.

The $dv \equiv d^3 r \equiv dV $ the infinitesimal volume element in the coordinate system, normally spherical.